# get the value in ListItem

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, controls, listitem

I´m trying to get the value of from all ListItems in a DropDown list, but when I treat them as a Control, I get an error:

> cannot convert type 'system.web.ui.control' to 'system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem'

My code:

```
if (c.GetType() == typeof(ListItem))
 string id = c.ID;
 string value = ((ListItem)(c)).Value; ///I get the error here (ListItem)(c)
```

How can I get those values? I would like to do it without knowing the ID from those elements.

Comment: is `c` ListItem or DropDownList?

Comment: `c` is Control 
`foreach (Control c in ctl.Controls)
            { .... } `

Comment: is `ctl` your dropdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
foreach (var item in ctl.Items) 
{
    var value = item.Value;
}
```

Comment: I have tried, but I get `represents a data item in a data-bound list control. This class can not get inherited`  at ((System.Web.UI.Webcontrols.ListItem)(c))

Comment: I guess you are trying to do this?

Comment: sorry for my delay in answering, wasn´t working on this. I have tried your "var item in ctl.Items" but I get an error that Syste.web.UI.Control doesn´t contain a definition for items.

Comment: Solved... ctl is not Dropdownlist Control, that´s why I couldn´t use ctl.Items. But I could use your information to solve the problem. Thanks.